# pandas: How to groupby and show count of unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in following format:

```
dateObs        website
---            --- 
2015-04-21     google.com
2015-08-13     facebook.com
2015-11-15     google.com
...
```

I want the output in this format:

```
year        count of distinct websites
---         ---
2015        2
...
```

I am able to obtain the total websites per year including duplicates using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
groupby = data.groupby(pd.to_datetime(data['dateObs']).dt.year).agg({'website':np.size})
```

How can I discard duplicates in the count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `.nunique()`:

`data.groupby(pd.to_datetime(data['dateObs']).dt.year).nunique()`

Answer (score 0):

is check if you can get what you want from a direct cross tabulation.

http://pandas.pydata.org//pandas-docs//version//0.17.0//generated//pandas.crosstab.html

Create a year column in your dataframe using the technique you outline and then do a cross tab with the columns year and website.